# Highstock plotting images that follow series when scrolling

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to create different backgrounds for 4 seasons with Highstock plugin.
I managed to display bands with different colors to show where seasons start and end. Then I stumble across this plugin:
http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/9/Pattern-Fill
but I'm only able to set recurring pattern to fill the band. Alternatively this could be fixed if something like CSS "no-repeat" would be achievable for SVG patterns.

How do I set an image in the middle of the band so it works as a nicely centered background? I tried markers first but this affects X axis labels. If not with the addBand feature, I think it's smarter to just plot images with highchart image renderer. The only thing is you can use X Y coordinates within the graph, but this is not the case of highstock where you can scroll the whole thing horizontally.

Comment: Could you attach a mockup of that chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple different approaches I ended up using this event for both x axes:

```
  afterSetExtremes : function(e) {
                                var xMin = e.min;
                                var xMax = e.max;
                                var ex = graph.xAxis[1].getExtremes();
                                if (ex.min != xMin || ex.max != xMax) graph.xAxis[1].setExtremes(xMin, xMax, true, false);
                        }
```

( [1] for 2nd axis' event and [0] for the 1st axis' event. )

Unfortunately I couldn't achieve the effect with linkedTo parameter. Maybe I was missing something or it's a feature to be used for a different scenario than mine (highstock, 2 X-axes).

Comment: This is known issue, just closed on master branch with `linkedTo` and `ordinal` axes. See more in this ticket: [#1417](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1417).